# How can I reduce subscriptions in RxJs and simplify my code

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

i got this code:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getEmployees();
    this.employeesService
      .reloadEmployees()
      .subscribe(() => this.getEmployees());

    this.employeesService.searchValue$
      .subscribe(value => this.employeesService.searchEmployees(value)
        .subscribe(el => this.allEmployees = el));
  }
```

Do you guys think that I can simplify that code? What should I do? I need to reduce that subscriptions, because at this point it doesnt look great

Comment: you can use switchMap (https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap)

Comment: What's happening in `getEmployees` ? Normally a getter method returns the thing it's getting, but you're not using that value, so I imagine there's some random side effect in that function you're interested in. What is it and why?

Answer (score 1):

you should avoid to subscribe inside another subscription.
You can sole it like this:

```js
this.employeesService.searchValue$.pipe(
  concatMap(value => this.employeesService.searchEmployees$(value))
).subscribe(el => this.allEmployees = el);
```

Comment: or maybe use switchMap instead of concatMap, I don't know what searchValue$ is doing...